# String concatenation in Python list (of strings) vs. numpy array (of strings)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, string-concatenation

For the purpose of my application, I can declare an array of strings in two ways:

1. As a list `strArr1 = [""] * 5` or
2. As a numpy array `strArr2 = numpy.empty([5], dtype=str)`

However, I see the following difference when I try to concatenate characters to array elements. In the first case, e.g.

```
strArr1[0] += 'a'
strArr1[0] += 'b'
```

gives me as expected `['ab', '', '', '', '']`.

In the second case however,

```
strArr2[0] += 'a'
strArr2[0] += 'b'
```

gives me the result `['a', '', '', '', '']`.

Why is concatenation not working as expected for the elements of numpy array? Also, given that I have the constraint that I must extend the elements of my array one character at a time, could anyone suggest an efficient and pythonic approach?

Thanks.

Comment: What else are you doing with these lists or arrays?  So far I don't see a good reason to use the array form.

Answer (score 0):

1. Numpy requires string arrays to have a fixed maximum length. You can use `strArr2 = numpy.empty([5], dtype='S10')`, where `10` is the maximum of string each item can hold, longer substring will be truncated.

   Or `strArr2 = numpy.empty([5], dtype=object)` that will enable you to store arbitrary python object into the array, including the `string`.

   See [Data type objects (dtype)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).
2. To improve the efficiency of extending string characters, you may try to use a Python list as the data type, then `append` each new character to the list. After all characters are finalized, use `join` to convert list back to string.

Comment: If I declare `strArr2 = numpy.empty([5], dtype='S10')`, each element is of type `numpy.bytes_`, and then I cannot concatenate chars/str to these elements.

Comment: On Py3 try `arr=np.zeros((5,), dtype='U10')` - unicode is standard on py3. Or mark your addition as byte string, e.g.  `arr[0] += b'abc'`

Comment: It works well for me (`Numpy 1.11.2 with Python 2.7.12`), and `type(strArr2[0])` gives `<type 'numpy.string_'>`. Anyway, using `dtype=object` or method 2 would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `numpy.empty` with `dtype='U10'` worked, although without marking my additions as bytes, i.e. w/o `b'abc'`, which fails.

Finally, for the sake of efficiency, I will follow Neo X's suggestion, which should avoid distribution specific anomalies in the behaviour.

P.S. I am using `Numpy 1.10.4 with Python 3.5.1`.